# How to select a point of a MaskLayer with python?

Tags: python, masking

I am trying to select points of a spline of a MaskLayer with Python. In the end I want to be able to temporarily store a group of points in a list so I can select and deselect a bunch of mask points with a hotkey via Python.
However, when I try this:

```
D.masks['Mask'].layers['MaskLayer'].splines[0].points[1].select = True
```

it only selects one handle of the point, but not the point itself. Am I missing something, or is it a bug or just not supported?
Because I can *check* if a point is selected or not with the above method, just the selecting with `select = True` acts weird.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the above method is actually the way to go, it just doesn't work due to a bug, which will hopefully be fixed soon.